# The inline-declared variable is not recognized

Tags: abap

I am having a problem where the system does not recognize a local variable that I have declared. The code is as follows:

```
DATA(lv_dmbtr) = ZSD_LGS-DMBTR.

  IF ( lv_dmbtr MOD 10000000 ) LE 9.
    lv_dmbtr / 10000000 = lv_tenmillions.      //Error line
    lv_tenmillions_check = lv_tenmillions MOD 1.

    IF lv_tenmillions_check > 0.
     "Convert
   ENDIF.

   IF lv_tenmillions_check < 0.
     "ZERO
   ENDIF.
  ENDIF.
```

The program gives me an error in the line that I have input in the program, where it says "*There is no LV_DMBTR statement. Please check the spelling.*"

May anyone of you know where the problem may be?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: The line is indeed not syntactically correct. It might seem obvious to you, but to me it looks like total gibberish. Can you explain in plan English what exactly you think this precise line does? Are you trying to assign a new value to `lv_tenmillion` or to `lv_dmbtr`.

Comment: @Philipp yes, it was a rookie mistake from my part, I wanted to do the opposite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
lv_dmbtr / 10000000 = lv_tenmillions.
```

is indeed not syntactically correct. I am as confused by that line as the ABAP interpreter. So I am not sure what exactly you are trying to accomplish with it. But I would guess that it seems to be some kind of assignment of a computation to some variable. In an assignment, the variable you assign to is always **on the left** of the `=` sign, while the expression which creates the value is **on the right** of the `=` sign.

So having a mathematical formula on the left-hand side of an equal sign makes no sense.

Either you are trying to say "lv_tenmillion shall be lv_dmbtr divided by 10000000". In that case the correct line would be

```
lv_tenmillions = lv_dmbtr / 10000000.
```

Or you are trying to say "one millionth of lv_dmbtr shall be equal to lv_tenmillion" which would be equivalent to saying "lv_dmbtr shall be equal to lv_tenmillion multiplied by 10000000" or

```
lv_dmbtr = lv_tenmillions * 10000000.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DATA(lv_dmbtr) = ZSD_LGS-DMBTR.
lv_dmbtr  = ZSD_LGS-DMBTR MOD 10000000
  IF lv_dmbtr MOD 10000000 LE 9.
    lv_dmbtr / 10000000 = lv_tenmillions.      //Error line
    lv_tenmillions_check = lv_tenmillions MOD 1.

    IF lv_tenmillions_check > 0.
     "Convert
   ENDIF.

   IF lv_tenmillions_check < 0.
     "ZERO
   ENDIF.
  ENDIF.
```